# can't display the line by line converted list on the webpage using python

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

this the first function that returns the list:

```
def getListOfKeyWord(keyword):
df=pd.read_excel('finaltrue.xlsx')
corpus=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    if keyword in df["text"][i]:
        corpus.append(df["text"][i])
return corpus
```

this the function where i printing the list as line by line:

```
def listing(result):
    x=0
    for item in range(0,len(result)):
        x+=1
        table = print(x,"",result[item])
    return table
```

this is the placeholder in html :

```
<div class="row center">
    {{key}}
  </div>
```

and here where i call the functions at the app.routing

```
 if request.method=='POST':
    word = request.form['kword']
    result=getListOfKeyWord(word)
    table=listing(result)
    return render_template('advance_search.html',key=table)
return render_template('advance_search.html')
```

**now i get a "none" word at the placeholder position**
**can anyone help please ?**

Comment: `print()` returns `None`, not the printed data.

Comment: `for item in range(0,len(result)):
        x+=1
        table = print(x,"",result[item])
    return table` is effectively reseting value of table evey time

Comment: You have indentation errors.

Comment: Also what type is the of lthe returned value by function `listing`? Is it a `list` or a string?

Comment: then how can i return the printed data ?
@KlausD.

Comment: You don't, you assemble the string with string formatting (f-strings, `.format()` or old `%` style)

Comment: @Epsi95
then how to fix it in order to return the value that contains the line by line list?

Comment: @KlausD.
can u please show me the syntax, how to write it ?
in order to fix it

Comment: Well, I could, but I think it would on the long run (and maybe even a shorter) that you educate yourself your string formatting. It is an important concept in Python. There are countless resources on the internet. One example: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @KlausD. 
i really searched but i don't have that much time cause of the deadline of my graduation project, so if u can help me to get it done faster, i will be thankful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot display a line by line list on flask webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242143/cannot-display-a-line-by-line-list-on-flask-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot assign the output of `print()` function to a variable.

The key issue here is your `listing` function. You can use this code instead:

```
def listing(result):
    table = '<br>'.join([ f'{i+1}- {item}' for i, item in enumerate(result) ])
    print(table)
    return table
```

You need to use `<br>` instead of `\n` to join the list since HTML will show `<br>` as new line, not `\n`.