# cannot display a line by line list on flask webpage

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

this is the function i used to return the list line by line :

```
def listing(table):
    x=0
    tab=[]
    for item in range(0,len(table)):
        x+=1
        result= f'{x}- {table[item]}' 
        tab.append(result)
    final = '\n'.join(tab)
    #print(final)
    return final
```

**and i made sure that it is printing line by line in the terminal**

this is the app.route :

```
if request.method=='POST':
    word = request.form['kword']
    result=getListOfKeyWord(word)
    table=listing(result)
    return render_template('advance_search.html',key=table)
return render_template('advance_search.html')
```

and this is the placeholder i'm trying to display the result in it :

```
<div class="row center">
    {{key}}
  </div>
```

**the result is displayed in the terminal line by line like desired, but on the webpage it is all concatinated side by side**

**can anyone help please ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather joining the list with `\n`, join it with `<br>` , `<br>` tag means break line.

```
final = '<br>'.join(tab)
```

Use safe filter to render it as html rather then plain text.

```
{{Key|safe}}
```

Comment: can u be more specific please ?

Comment: I have updated the answer, I am as specific as I can be.

Answer (score 0):

As @charchit pointed out, you should use `<br>` (HTML line break) to join your list so that new line can be displayed in your HTML page.

Aside from that, it seems you would like to loop through a list to get both index and value. You actually can do it with `enumerate()` function. By combining with Python list comprehension, your `listing()` function can be rewritten as below:

```
def listing(table):
    final = '<br>'.join([f'{i+1}- {item}' for i, item in enumerate(table)])
    print(final)
    return final
```